# How to use an alternative for in_array with a database not array

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an array of IP addresses that I use with `in_array` to deny people in the following code.

```
$deny = array("111.222.333.444","999.555.444.222");
if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) {
header("location: http://google.com/");
exit();
}
```

Is there an alternative to `in_array` using a database. If I have a database of IP addresses how can I check the database for the IP address and redirect using the header?

Comment: Just query the database with the ip of the user and if you get a result deny access.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MySQLi:

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) AS denied
          FROM table_of_ips
          WHERE ip = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."'
          LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link, $query));

if ($result['denied']) {
  header("location: http://google.com/");
  exit;  
}
```

In essence, just SELECT where the IP matches the client IP, if you get a result, it's denied.